# Improve Byte Conversion in Java

Tags: java

i need some help improving the following code - there is a conversion between byte and int, that does not work in all cases - I need some feedback to find and solve possible issues involving byteToInt IntToByte conversion

```
int start = 02;
int stepSize = 256;
int bytesLeftToRead = 
// [0][1] encode a hex value as two bytes
// this part only works for [0] > 0 and [0] < 10 -- other restrictions?
response[0]*256 + Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(response[1] + 256), 16);

while(bytesLeftToRead > 0){

    // convert where to start from int to two bytes
    cmdReadPD[2] = (byte) (start / 256);
    cmdReadPD[3] = (byte) (start % 256);

    if(stepSize > bytesLeftToRead){
        stepSize = bytesLeftToRead;
    }

    // encode stepsize in two bytes
    cmdReadPD[5] = (byte) (stepSize / 256);
    cmdReadPD[6] = (byte) (stepSize % 256);

    start += stepSize;
    bytesLeftToRead -= stepSize;
    read(cmdReadPD, stepSize);
}
```

Comment: What's `Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(response[1] + 256), 16)` for in your code?

Comment: response[1] encodes the first two digits of a hex number - since byte can be negative, I have to add 256 - then I use toHexString to convert the int value to a hexString and use parseInt to get the integer value of that hex

Comment: that's way too elaborated. See my answer, `((response[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (response[1] & 0xFF)` will do just fine, be easier to understand, and _way_ faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(byte) ((start >> 8) & 0xFF);` and `(byte) (start & 0xFF);`.

Note though it will only help for ints lower than 2^16.

To recollect bytes to int, use `(lo & 0xFF) | ((hi & 0xff) << 8)`: `&` will widen the `byte` to an int, making negative bytes positive ints; shift and `|` will recollect the value.

Comment: just noticed that you forgot some brackets! it is actually ((hi & 0xFF) << 8)

Answer (score 0):

I would use ByteBuffer to read and write short (signed) or char (unsigned) values.

```
ByteBuffer response = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);// .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);  if you need to change it.
ByteBuffer cmdReadPD = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);

int reponseCode = response.getChar(0);

while(cmdReadPD.remaining() > 0){
    // convert where to start from int to two bytes
    cmdReadPD.setshort(2, (short) start);

    if(stepSize > bytesLeftToRead)
        stepSize = bytesLeftToRead;

    // encode stepsize in two bytes
    cmdReadPD.setshort(4, (short) stepSize);
```